# Jquery not working with xampp

Tags: jquery, xampp

Using xampp, I cant get a jquery script to work (creates a modal box). However, if I just execute the html (i.e. go to the file in the htdocs folder instead of localhost) then it works fine. Anyone know why or how I Can get it to work?

This is the code, and again, it works FINE if I do not navigate to localhost, so I'm not sure if I need to do something else with xampp? I did try and use a local file path to the jquery file, and then tried linking through localhost, so that's not the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://localhost/avesi/jquery.paulund_modal_box.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login to Web App</h1>
      <form method="post" action="checklogin.php">
        <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
        <class="submit"><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
      </form>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="paulund_modal">Click Here</a>


<button type = "button" id="dialog">Click Me!</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.paulund_modal').paulund_modal_box();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: The Jquery isn't mine, I was just trying to get modals working at all.

Comment: first: change the `src="https://localhost/avesi/`..." to `src="/avesi/...` 
and load jquery also from localhost. and at the end of the document, before your custom script.

Comment: nvm it works as /avesi/... Not sure what you mean at the end of the doc before the script though?

Comment: output of debug console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download jQuery to your *root/js* folder as: */js/jquery.min.js* then change the code:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/avesi/jquery.paulund_modal_box.js"></script>
```

Comment: That was it! Any reason why it doesn't work linked like that to Google?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Remove this line

```
<script src="https://localhost/avesi/jquery.paulund_modal_box.js"></script>
```

Hope this will be solved

There will be problem with your xamp. Your xamp will be offline.

Comment: If you mean to just remove the src and do all the coding in the actually html doc, I did that with exact same result. Works if I just double click the file, going through localhost though it doesnt work still.

Comment: type this in your browser :https://localhost/avesi/jquery.paulund_modal_box.js if it open your file, then good, other wise there is problem with your given url or your xamp is not running successfully